# Why would we want to know the distance between two nominal values?

Tags: distance, data-mining

So i have a question from my databases class asking to find the distance between two values of the same attribute (attribute: work type; and the possible values: electrical, plumbing, repairs). so the distance between plumbing and repairs. I converted the values into sub attributes and put in binary numbers to represent the presence or absence of the value so the new values look like this (electrical: 100, plumbing: 010, repairs: 001). I can now calculate the hamming distance between the two values. But my question is, in the real world why would we even want to know the distance between two nominal values when they are obviously already different and one is not more valuable than the other?

Comment: if A is "closer" to B than to C, then A is more similar to B than to C. you can use it for comparing similarity, clustering, etc

Comment: That makes sense so because they are all different it will result in 3 clearly separate clusters right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you *only* have such variables it bears little use.

But assuming you additionally have the attributes "age" and "income", and you want to cluster this data set, then you need a distance function.

Unfortunately, binary coding is a hack that does not work very well. You still need to carefully normalize the data, but what are the *correct* weights for age, income, job? You get some result, but with other weights you may as well get a very different result, too.